# Parsing a list of objects got from an API

Tags: java, spring, parsing, retrofit

Hi i am using retrofit to call my API with spring boot.

API Response

```
    [
         {
             "name": "whishky",
             "price": 1000
         },
         {
             "name": "vodka",
             "price": 200
         }
    ]
```

My pojo class looks like

```
public class MyResponse {
    List<MyObject> resp;
}
```

And MyObject class looks like

```
public class MyObject implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("price")
    private Double price;
}
```

API call

```
Call<MyResponse> saveRequestCall = MyApi.fetchData(request);
Response<MyResponse> execute = saveRequestCall.execute();
```

Now the problem is when i call the API i am getting the exception

```
2020-04-25 18:08:18,895 ERROR c.s.e.b.XYZServiceImpl Error in fetching datawith exception com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `zzz.MyResponse` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (InputStreamReader); line: 1, column: 1]
```

Any help will be appreciated regarding how i can parse this.

Comment: That JSON response seems to be incorrect format for me

Comment: If the server is supposed to return JSON, then it messed up. Fix the server.

Comment: Corrected the response.

Comment: While you've gotten two answers below, I do think it's useful to know: For the Jackson objectmapper to (de)serialize POJO's (convert 'em into JSON strings), all POJO's need to implement the Serializable interface. In your case MyObject does implement it but MyResponse (which contains a list of MyObjects) does not. So Jackson cannot serialize MyResponse. I prefer the answers below, but this is useful to know for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be mapping to `MyResponse` because it's excepecting something like

```
{
  "resp": [
    {
       "name": "whishky",
       "price": 1000
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

It should be fixed if you use

```java
Call<List<MyObject>> saveRequestCall = MyApi.fetchData(request);
Response<List<MyObject>> execute = saveRequestCall.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

The above json represent `JSONArray` of `JSONObject` with two properties `name` and `price`, so you don't need to wrap `List<MyObject> resp` in another class, you can directly deserialize json into `List<MyObject>`

```
Call<List<MyObject>> saveRequestCall = MyApi.fetchData(request);
Response<List<MyObject>> execute = saveRequestCall.execute();
```